# how to move wordpress from root to a new directory on hostgator?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

Iam using hostgator and I want to move my wordpress application from the root directory 'home/username/' to a new directory which is 'home/username/mysite' and the website url should be mysite.com, I tried to do that but now my website url is mysite.com/mysite, so what I could do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hostgator cPanel does not allow you to change the root folder of the primary domain to anything other than the default *public_html* folder yourself. If you really need to do it, [you need to contact their migrations department](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/document-root-changes). Also, please note that this only works for a VPS or a Dedicated server.

There is, however, a workaround to avoid going through this process to achieve the desired result:

1. Change the primary domain name on your Hostgator account to something else. (*mynewsite.com*)
2. Now create an add-on domain with the original domain name. (*mysite.com*)
3. Point the add-on domain mysite.com to the new folder that contains the Wordpress installation. (*home/username/mysite*)
4. Your original domain name will now point to the new folder as you desired.

It's not pretty, I admit, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by Hostgator. [Please read this](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/document-root-changes)